# msal.js using Authorization Code Grant without secret

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

the [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa) for msal.js are still using implicit Grant Flow which seems to be vulnerable and shouldn't be used anymore according to this [document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-parecki-oauth-browser-based-apps-02) from IETF.

My question is: Is it possible to use the code Grant Flow using the msal.js, and if yes, does someone maybe have a sample of how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code sample. It shows how to implement authorization code flow with SPA:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2